# Java several enums as getter/setter

Tags: java, enums, getter

I wanted to use enum class to assign book formats to book object. Issue that I have encountered is that some books have 1 format and other have several.

```
public enum Format {
    HARD_COVER, PAPERBACK, E_BOOK, AUDIOBOOK
}
```

Let's say that first book have only 1 format while second book have all formats. How can I solve it with getters/setters?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I solve it with getters/setters?

I wouldn't do this since in my experience, getters and setters are for setting single properties.  If I have a class that requires a collection of property, then I'd have the class contain a List for this:

```
List<Format> formats = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then:

```
public void addFormat(Format format) {
    formats.add(format);  // add to the ArrayList of Format
}
```

and similarly a `removeFormat(Format format)` method for removing from the List.

---

Edit: as correctly stated by Dorian Gray in comments, it would be better that the collection of Formats be a `Set<Format> initialized as an` EnumSet` since this would prevent duplicate Formats being added to the collection.

```
Set<Format> formatSet = EnumSet.noneOf(Format.class);
```

Comment: I would propably use `Set<Format> formats = EnumSet.noneOf(Format.class);` instead - it is more efficient and doesn't allow you to add the same format more then once.

Comment: @DorianGray: I like your idea better than mine

Comment: @DorianGray: if you don't mind, I have added your idea to my answer. If you'd rather write your own answer (or object for other reason), I will remove this

Comment: It's fine for me. I didn't want to copy your part for my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with **Bitwise Operators** to have one property with the possibility of having multiple values.

Have Enums with `int` values like this:

```
public enum Format {
    HARD_COVER(1),
    PAPERBACK(2),
    E_BOOK(4),
    AUDIOBOOK(8);

    public final int value;

    Format(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In your `Book` class add an `int` property called `format` instead of a `Format` property. Also create a method called `isFormat` that returns a `boolean` value according to its `Format` parameter:

```
class Book {
    private int format;

    public Book(int format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public boolean isFormat(Format format) {
        return format.value == (this.format & format.value); // &: bitwise and
    }
}
```

Finally create a book adding formats separated by | (bitwise or):

```
Book book = new Book(Format.E_BOOK.value | Format.HARD_COVER.value | Format.AUDIOBOOK.value);
```

And check its formats like this:

```
System.out.println("Is paperback?: " + book.isFormat(Format.PAPERBACK));
System.out.println("Is hard cover?: " + book.isFormat(Format.HARD_COVER));
System.out.println("Is audio book?: " + book.isFormat(Format.AUDIOBOOK));
System.out.println("Is E-book?: " + book.isFormat(Format.E_BOOK));
```

The result of this execution is this:

```
Is paperback?: false
Is hard cover?: true
Is audio book?: true
Is E-book?: true
```

Comment: It is a good idea but looking at let's say 50 books number of lines that I will need to create might be enormous

Comment: Why not just use an `EnumSet` instead of your bit wise operations?